# Xubuntu 13.10 Blank Desktop after Update

Tags: xubuntu, 13.10, xfce

I'm using Xubuntu and upgraded to 13.10 as the system dialog suggested it.
However, after rebooting and logging in (the Loginscreen still perfectly works), I only see a black Desktop with an invisible mouse cursor, and my taskbar on the bottom. The invisible mouse is still useable as onMouseOver Effects apply.

After searching through the internet for a solution (the Guest Login still perfectly works), it seemed like the ATI drivers may be the root of evil here and it had been suggested to remove all fglrx packages and continue with the open source driver.

After uninstalling fglrx and rebooting, I'm experiencing exactly the same issues as mentioned in this question: [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

No Taskbar, no Mouse, just the plain Desktop Background. The problem at this point, however, is, that I use Xubuntu and xfce and none of the solutions of the mentioned thread was applicable for me so far as I don't have unity or compiz.

Comment: Please post Xorg's log from `/var/log`, accessible via Ctrl+Alt+F1.

Comment: You said this is the same as in [that question](http://askubuntu.com/q/17381) but that none of the answers there have helped. If you're still having this problem, you may want to go back and see if any newer answers (or expanded/improved answers) there will solve this. If still nothing there helps, please *edit this question* to provide details about *all the possible solutions* there that did not work, and how/why. For example, you can tell us everything you tried and exactly what happened. Without that info, this isn't really separate (and thus may be duped to it or closed as unclear).

Answer (score 0):

This is a last-chance solution, offered only if no one has a better solution. Either

A) do Ctrl-Alt-F1 which will get you into a text-only terminal emulation window, or

B) reboot from a LiveCD or flash drive

-

then backup everything in and under home to a flash drive or other external storage.

Then, wipe the hard drive completely and reinstall 13.10 from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/363915/upgrading-from-12-04-to-12-10-not-booting/363928#363928)

The problem is in your Kernel, maybe you have two.

I had this problem too.

The solution is you burn a DVD, upgrade from DVD Ubuntu 12.10

But it's better you burn 13.10 version and upgrade from DVD.

You will not loose any files, music, pictures, ISO in your VM, etc.

Comment: This doesn't really address this situation.  The upgrade is done.  The user is trying to rectify the upgrade into something that works.